# ESP8266 ESP-01 only responds "Recv x bytes" after an HTTPS request

Tags: esp8266

I'm using ESP8266 ESP-01 for wifi data transfer.

When I send the request for 80 server's port, the data is successfully returned.

REQ: `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server.com\r\n\r\n`

But when I send this request over 443 server's port, the data received is "Recv 50 bytes...  ...SEND OK..."

It's possibly an ESP or an HTTPS Headers problem? What i mean is what is needed to transform the Headers from HTTP to HTTPS (I did'nt saw any diference in Postman, but in Postman works only changing the server's port)?

- Sequence in HTTP:

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","myserver.com\",80"\r\n`

`AT+CIPSEND=PKG_SIZE\r\n`

`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myserver.com\r\n`

Works OK.

- Sequence in HTTPS:

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","myserver.com\",443"\r\n`

`AT+CIPSEND=PKG_SIZE\r\n`

`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myserver.com\r\n`

Doesn't work.

Comment: How many bytes are you actually sending?

Comment: The reponse is "Recv x  bytes" where x is the bytes sent in my request.
The GET above have 50 bytes.

Comment: Are you using the AT firmware? Show the AT commands you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect via SSL instead of bare TCP:

```
AT+CIPSTART="SSL","myserver.com",443
```

Comment: The module reposnds: "busy p...\r\n\r\nERROR\r\nCLOSED\r\n. Ive found in another forum that this model (ESP-01) maybe doesn't support HTTPS...

Comment: Jimmy, thank you. I tested in ESP32 and worked in 443 PORT. in ESP8266_ESP01 still doesn't work but ESP32 is far enough.